# "Invalid content was found starting with element 'http:basicAuthSupplier'" while building Apache CXF project

Tags: java, xml, spring, cxf

hi am building a web application using maven, eclipse,tomcat.
after resolving my dependency, am getting this error. anyone can help how to solve this?

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http:basicAuthSupplier'.One of '{"http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":client, "http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":authorization, "http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":proxyAuthorization,"http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":tlsClientParameters, "http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":authSupplier, "http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration":trustDecider}' is expected.  jaxws-web-context.xml
```

here the code where am getting this error:

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:basicAuthSupplier class="org.skyway.spring.util.webservice.cxf.HttpBasicAuthenticationSupplier" />
</http:conduit>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message lists all allowed XML elements.

As you can see in the list, there is no prefix `basicAuthSupplier`. Try `authSupplier` instead:

```
<http:authSupplier class="org.skyway.spring.util.webservice.cxf.HttpBasicAuthenticationSupplier" />
```

Related:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4080
- http://documentation.progress.com/infocenter/sonic/8.5/index.jsp?topic=/com.sonicsw.tools.sonicconnect.doc/auth_supplier_config.html
- http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduit.html

Comment: i try it but now am having this error:

The prefix "authSupplier" for element "authSupplier:basicAuthSupplier" is not bound.